# Have set datasource and delegate of TableView inside ViewController but nothing happening

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a UITableView inside a UIViewController and I think I´v done all the nescesary steps
to set it up but I get no response from the tableView when putting an NSLog inside the requiered methods of it´s protocol

[image]

I tell the UITableView that I will implement it´s protocols

```
@interface SubSelectionTableViewWithMenuVC : UIViewController <CustomTableViewCellDelegate,
                                                                UITableViewDelegate,
                                                                UITableViewDataSource,
                                                                TableViewModelDelegate>
```

I got the tableView outlet set up in the header

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView  *tableView;
```

In `ViewDidLoad` I set the delegate to self.

```
self.tableView.delegate = self;
self.tableView.dataSource = self;
```

And I implement the required delegate methods

```
– tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: 

– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:
```

But nothing happens, I did a NSLog in the ViewDidLoad of the tableView object, it tells me this:

```
tableView: <UITableView: 0x1d43aa00; frame = (0 0; 0 0); clipsToBounds = YES;
autoresize = TM+BM; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x1cdc54f0>; layer = <CALayer:
0x1cdc5350>; contentOffset: {0, 0}>
```

Required delegate methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    NSLog(@"num of sections");
    return 1;
}

#pragma mark - UI set cell contents


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cell for row at indepath");
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = CELL_IDENTIFIER_LECTURES;
    CustomTableViewCell *cell = (CustomTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.indexPath = indexPath;
    cell.delegate = self;

    // Configure cell
    [cell.mainLabel setText:[self titleForRow:indexPath.row]];
    [cell.numberLabel setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", indexPath.row + 1]];
    cell.state = [self restoreTagButtonStateForCell:cell];

    // perform selector on cell to update and show its last stored state
    if ([cell respondsToSelector:@selector(updateButtonImageState)]) {
        [cell performSelector:@selector(updateButtonImageState)];
    } else {
        [NSException raise:NSGenericException format:@"cell does not respond to selector"];
    }

    // Setting the Highligthed color of selected cell
    UIView *goldenColor = [[UIView alloc] init];
    goldenColor.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.824 green:0.749    blue:0.553 alpha:1.0f];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView = goldenColor;

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: What do you have in the UITableView's datasource methods?

Comment: updated the question. I noticed something weird, sometimes it NSLogs cellForRowAtIndexPath and other times numberOfSectionsInTableView: never both

Comment: How many rows do you return?

Comment: @AbdullahShafique: facepalm! 0 hehe - problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is because you are not implementing your `– tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method. Implement this method and return the amount you need.